# Flutter - Notification sent with Firebase Messaging drops late

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have installed Firebase in my Flutter project. I'm sending notifications via Messaging. However, 10-15 minutes after sending, the notification goes away. Why could this be? How can I speed up the time?

Sometimes it doesn't send the notification at all.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to request the permissions the following code:

```
 FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );
```